# How to clean created docker image on self hosted server?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline on azure platform that builds the image of my application and pushed the docker hub.

The steps are:

```
  - stage: DockerizeApp
    condition: succeeded()
    displayName: Dockerize App
    jobs:
      - job: BuildDockerImage
        displayName: Build Docker Image Job
        steps:
            - task: Docker@2
              displayName: Build Docker Image
              inputs:
                repository: $(imageName)
                command: build
                dockerFile: '**/Dockerfile'
                tags: "latest"
      - job: PushDockerImage
        displayName: Push Docker Image Job
        dependsOn: BuildDockerImage
        condition: succeeded()
        steps:
            - task: Docker@2
              displayName: Push Image
              inputs:
                containerRegistry: $(dockerHub)
                repository: $(imageName)
                command: push
                tags: "latest"
```

Build step creates a new image and adds it to my docker images named `app/xyz:latest`. But all build creates a new image on my computer. The old ona is tagged as `<none>`. So how can I clean images after push it to docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

To clean up all unused or dangling images, containers, volumes, and networks, you can try the following command lines.

1. Remove any images, containers, volumes, and networks that are dangling (not tagged or associated with a container).

   ```sh
   docker system prune
   ```
2. Remove any stopped containers and all unused images (not just dangling images), add the **`-a`** flag to the command.

   ```sh
   docker system prune -a
   ```

For more details, you can reference the following articles:

- [**docker system prune**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)
- [**docker rmi**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/)
- [**docker image prune**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)
- [**How To Remove Docker Images, Containers, and Volumes**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes)